# Enums inside of a C++ class

Tags: c++, enums

I am trying to use a class that has an enum type declared inside the class like so:

```
class x {
public:
    x(int);
    x( const x &);
    virtual ~x();
    x & operator=(const x &);
    virtual double operator()() const;

    typedef enum  {
        LINEAR = 0,      /// Perform linear interpolation on the table
        DIPARABOLIC = 1  /// Perform parabolic interpolation on the table
    } XEnumType; 
};
```

I need to declare an instance of this class and initialize the enum type.  I come from C# and normally see enums declared OUTSIDE of a class, not INSIDE like it is here.  How do I initialize the enum type.  For example, I want to do something like this:

```
x myX(10);   
myX.XEnumType = Linear;
```

Obviously this doesn't work.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 9):

First you need to declare a variable that is of the type `XEnumType` within your class
Then you can access the actual enumeration values using the class name for scope: `x::LINEAR` or `x::DIPARABOLIC`

```
class x{
 //Your other stuff

XEnumType myEnum;
};

int main(void)
{
    x myNewClass();
    x.myEnum = x::LINEAR;
}
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it.  Also, you should get rid of that `typedef` keyword in front to the enum (just use `enum XEnumType {...}`) -- you're in C++ now.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to have it, but you are right, the typedef is unnecessary in c++

Answer (score 9):

First: Don't use `typedef`. Instead, put the name of the enumeration in its head

```
enum XEnumType {
    LINEAR = 0,      /// Perform linear interpolation on the table
    DIPARABOLIC = 1  /// Perform parabolic interpolation on the table
};
```

In a nutshell, doing like you did will behave *mostly* the same, but in arcane corner cases will be different. The syntax you used will behave very different from the syntax I used above only in C.

Second: That just defines a type. But you want to define an object of that enumeration. Do so:

```
XEnumType e;
```

In summary:

```
class x {
    /* ... stays the same ... */

    enum XEnumType {
        LINEAR = 0,      /// Perform linear interpolation on the table
        DIPARABOLIC = 1  /// Perform parabolic interpolation on the table
    }; 

    XEnumType e;
};

void someFunction() {
    x myX(10);
    myX.e = x::LINEAR;
}
```

Comment: "Don't use typedef." Could you explain why not?

Comment: @dpk: In C, declaring a `struct MyStruct {};` required you to always refer to the type as `struct MyStruct`. That is why people did a `typedef struct {} MyStruct;`, so they could use just `MyStruct` as the type. C++ does not have this requirement; you can declare `struct MyStruct {};` and still use `MyStruct` as the type. Applying `typedef` in this context is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

```
enum XEnumType {
    LINEAR, DIPARABOLIC
};

class x {    
    public:    
      x(int);    
      x( const x &);    
      virtual ~x();    
      x & operator=(const x &);    
      virtual double operator()() const;    
      XEnumType my_enum;
};
```

Usage:

```
x myX(10);
myX.my_enum = LINEAR;
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared a new type : `XEnumType`. You have to create a field of that type inside `x` class.
.
For example:

```
class x {

public:
    x(int);
    x( const x &);
    virtual ~x();
    x & operator=(const x &);
    virtual double operator()() const;
typedef enum  {
    LINEAR = 0,      /// Perform linear interpolation on the table
    DIPARABOLIC = 1  /// Perform parabolic interpolation on the table
} XEnumType; 
public:
XEnumType type;
};
```

Then you can access to it that way:

```
x foo(10);
foo.type = LINEAR;
```

Comment: Hi @Heisenbug: I think simply calling `LINEAR` won't work. You need to call with `x::LINEAR`.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
typedef enum  {
    LINEAR = 0,      /// Perform linear interpolation on the table
    DIPARABOLIC = 1  /// Perform parabolic interpolation on the table
} XEnumType;
```

defines a *type* called `XEnumType`, actually this is redundant anyway - prefer something like:

```
enum XEnumType
{
  LINEAR = 0,      /// Perform linear interpolation on the table
  DIPARABOLIC = 1  /// Perform parabolic interpolation on the table
};
```

Now you need to define a member of this type in your class

```
XEnumType _eType;
```

In your constructor, then you can initialize to whatever

```
x::x(int ) : _eType(x::LINEAR) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first assume some preconditions:

- Class `x` is from a third-party library and thus cannot be changed.
- Class `x` defines some integer constants with the help of an enum.
- Class `x` is supposed to be initialized with either one of the constants `LINEAR` or `DIPARABOLIC`.

Your problem is that these constant values are declared within class `x`. So to initialize an instance of `x` you need to specify the scope:

Instead of

```
x myX(10);   
myX.XEnumType = Linear;
```

try

```
x myX(x::LINEAR);
```

By specifying `x::` you provide the scope of the constant.